# How to solve [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten on vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My view is like this :

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    ...
        <star :value="{{ $data['rating'] }}"></star>
    ...
</div>
```

My star component is like this :

```
<template>
    <span class="rating" :class='{"disable-all-rating": !!value}'>
        <template v-for="item in items">
            <label class="radio-inline input-star" :class="{'is-selected': ((starValue>= item.value) && starValue!= null)}">
                <input type="radio" class="input-rating" v-model="starValue" @click="rate(item.value)">
            </label>
        </template>
    </span>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        props: {
            'value': null
        },
        computed: {
            starValue () {
                return this.temp_value
            }
        },
        data(){
            return{
                items: [
                    {value: 5},
                    {value: 4},
                    {value: 3},
                    {value: 2},
                    {value: 1}
                ],
                temp_value: null,
            }
        },
        methods:{
            rate: function (star) {           
               this.$http.post(window.BaseUrl + '/star', {star: star});                         
               this.temp_value = star;                         
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

My css is like this :

```
span.rating {
  direction: rtl;
  display: inline-block;
}

span.rating .input-star {
  background: url("../img/star.png") 0 -16px;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

span.rating .input-star:hover, span.rating .input-star:hover ~ .input-star {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

span.rating .is-selected{
   background-position: 0 0;
}

span.rating .is-disabled{
   cursor: default;
}

span.rating .input-star .input-rating {
  display: none;
}
```

When I click the star, there exist error on the console like this :

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be
>   overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a
>   data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being
>   mutated: "value"  (found in  at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\resources\assets\js\components\Star.vue)

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 7):

You need to make the computed with a getter and a setter and then use `$emit` to update the prop e.g:

```
    computed: {
        starValue:{ 
            get:function () {
                return this.temp_value
            },
            set: function(newValue){
                // $emit is the correct way to update props:
                this.$emit('update:value', newValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You're changing the `value` property here.

```
return this.value = star;
```

And possibly here.

```
v-model="value"
```

The warning means that whenever your view is re-rendered, the `value` property is going to be set to `$data['rating']`, overwriting whatever you did inside the start component.

Instead of mutating the property inside your component, when someone clicks a star, you probably want to `$emit` that the component has changed and let your view change `$data['rating']`, which will re-render the star component properly.

See the Vue documentation regarding [component composition](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components).

Comment: I'm still confused implement it

Comment: @samueltoh Are you still getting the warning with the code as shown in your question?

Comment: https://jakzaizzat.com/avoid-mutating-a-prop-directly/

Answer (score 0):

The warning suggests not modifying a prop's value directly as doing so you would lose the change anyway if the data at the parent component changes.

That said, here in your method:

```
methods: {
  rate: function (star) {
    var self = this;
    if (!this.disabled) {
        this.$http.post(window.BaseUrl + '/star', {star: star}).then(function (response) {
            console.log('submitted');
        });
        this.temp_value = star;
        // return this.value = star; - remove this line
    }
  }
}
```

and add a [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example) property like so:

```
computed: {
  starValue () {
    return this.temp_value
  }
}
```

Comment: I had try it. But, it impact to other codes. Could you update your answer with a more complete?

Comment: @samueltoh Can you tell me how are you using `value`? and why it is affecting other places?

Comment: Look at my question. I update the code. I try like that

Comment: @samueltoh Sorry but I am not able to see where you are using value, for your case you need to use `v-model` but how, is something I can help with only when I understand your current usage.

Comment: This :`props: {
            'value': null
        },`. It's the value. I had update my code. I've updated my code according to your answer. My code use v-model too